# Why is jquery-ui not loaded with webpack

Tags: jquery-ui, typescript, autocomplete, webpack, .net-core

I am trying to include jquery-ui in my .NET Core project so that I can use `autocomplete` in one of my `typescript` files. I am able to use `webpack` to copy my `node_modules` files to my root folder. I have also included the `jquery-ui.js` file in my master layout, and added `require("jquery-ui-bundle");` to my entry file.

But when i run my project, i get a console error stating `$(...)autocomplete is not a function`, when i check the sources tab in developer tools, I do not see the `jquery-ui` file added, although i see the other libraries such as `jquery` which i have added the same way. I am not sure what i am missing. See configurations below.

**webpack.config.js**

```
/// <reference path="wwwroot/lib/datatables/js/jquery.datatables.js" />
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
var glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    entry: "./Scripts/entry.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "./wwwroot/Scripts/[name].js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".ts", ".less"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts/, exclude: [/node_modules/, /typings/], loader: "ts-loader" },
            { test: /\.less/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader") },
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: "url-loader?limit-100000&name/css/[hash].[ext]" },
            {
                test: /datatables\.net.*/,
                loader: "imports?define=>false"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[
        new ExtractTextPlugin("./wwwroot/css/site.css", { allChunks: true }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: "node_modules/jquery/dist", to: "./wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist" },
            { from: "node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle", to: "./wwwroot/lib/jquery-ui-bundle" },
            { from: "node_modules/bootstrap/dist", to: "./wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist" },
            { from: "node_modules/datatables.net/js", to: "./wwwroot/lib/datatables/js" },
            { from: "node_modules/datatables.net-bs/js", to: "./wwwroot/css/datatables/js" },
            { from: "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css", to: "./wwwroot/css/datatables/css" },
            { from: "node_modules/datatables.net-bs/css", to: "./wwwroot/css/datatables/css" },
            { from: "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/images", to: "./wwwroot/css/datatables/css" }
        ])
    ],

    watch: true
}
```

**typescript entry file**

```
import $ = require("jquery");
require("jquery-ui-bundle");
```

**Script included in layout page**

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/css/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</environment>
```

**File path (wwwroot)**
[image]

**Chrome developer tools does not show jquery ui under lib folder**
[image]

Comment: Just after a glance at your config file, maybe webpack is confused because you have no loader for .js configured (assuming the jquery-ui lib is js only)?

Comment: @Fionn yeah its js only, is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: If you use babel something like { test: /\.js$/, use: "babel-loader"} - have never used js without the babel loader so i don't know if you need a rule for plain JS else. Also if you use webpack 2+ the loaders are now under module.rules instread of module.loaders.